# JSON parse JSON with changing Key and changing type of value (list or string)

Tags: json, powerbi, powerquery, directquery

I have JSON Rows which can change key and type of values

changing keys in examples are

`015913d2e43d41ef98e6e5c8dc90cd09_2_1` and
`e8c93befe4a34bcabbf604e352a41a2d_2_1`

changing types of values are

list (Row 1):

```
"answer": [
          "<i>GET</i>\n",
          "<i>PUT</i>\n",
          "<i>POST</i>\n",
          "<i>TRACE</i>\n",
          "<i>HEAD</i>\n",
          "<i>DELETE</i>\n"
        ],
```

text (Row 2):

```
"answer": "Может быть во всех",
```

Examples of rows:

row 1

```
{
  "event": {
    "submission": {
      "015913d2e43d41ef98e6e5c8dc90cd09_2_1": {
        "question": "Какие виды <i>HTTP</i> запросов могут внести изменения на сервере (в общем случае)?",
        "answer": [
          "<i>GET</i>\n",
          "<i>PUT</i>\n",
          "<i>POST</i>\n",
          "<i>TRACE</i>\n",
          "<i>HEAD</i>\n",
          "<i>DELETE</i>\n"
        ],
        "response_type": "choiceresponse",
        "input_type": "checkboxgroup",
        "correct": false,
        "variant": "",
        "group_label": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

row 2

```
{
  "event": {
    "submission": {
      "e8c93befe4a34bcabbf604e352a41a2d_2_1": {
        "question": "В запросах какого типа может быть использована <i>RCE</i>?",
        "answer": "Может быть во всех",
        "response_type": "multiplechoiceresponse",
        "input_type": "choicegroup",
        "correct": true,
        "variant": "",
        "group_label": ""
      }
    }
  }
}
```

[Here is the Image in Power Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKe3i.jpg)

How can extract data from the List in Direct Power Query?

If I write this

`= Table.AddColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "answer_s", each Record.Field([raw_event][event][submission],[question_id])[answer]{0})`

I get error with text types answers
[image, error with text types](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lg3rS.jpg)

If i write this:
`= Table.AddColumn(#"Duplicated Column", "answer_s", each Record.Field([raw_event][event][submission],[question_id])[answer])`

[I get Lists](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ByC8.jpg)

I have already asked the question with parsing JSON
[JSON parsing with changing keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78205099/json-parsing-with-changing-keys/78206024#78206024)

the result I would like to receive should be looks like
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aC02l.png)
thanks!

Comment: Did you accept the answer that was provided to the other question you asked, to mark the issue as solved?